# Linear algebra nilpotency

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following question

> (a) A complex $n\times n$ matrix is said to be unitpotent if $U-I$ is nilpotent, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Show that $U$ is unipotent if and only if $1$ is the only eigenvalue of $U$
>
> (b) Let $T$ be an invertible complex matrix. By considering the Jordan form of $T$, show that there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that
> $$
> PTP^{-1} = D_0 + N
> $$
> where $D_0$ is an invertible diagonal matrix, $N$ is an upper triangular matrix with zeros in the diagonal, and $D_0N = ND_0$.
>
> (c) Set $D = P^{-1}D_0P$ and show that $U = D^{-1}T$ is unipotent
>
> (d) Conclude that any invertible matrix $T$ can be written as $T = DU$ where $D$ is diagonalizable, $U$ is unipotent, and $DU = UD$.

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHbTk.png)

I was able to do (a) (b) and (d) but I am stuck on (c).  I tried showing that $U-I$ is nilpotent but that  got me nowhere. I also tried to showing that $U$ has only eigen value $1$ but that got me to no avail. I can't seem to use $D_0 N= N D_0$. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Observe that from $PTP^{-1} = D_0 + N$ you have $T = P^{-1}D_0P + P^{-1}NP$. Thus
\begin{eqnarray*}
U & = & D^{-1}T = P^{-1}D^{-1}_0P \cdot (P^{-1}D_0P + P^{-1}NP) \\
& = & I + P^{-1}(D^{-1}_0 N)P.
\end{eqnarray*}
Does that help you?

Comment: Oh my god, I made a silly mistake when I was attempting this calculation. I think I see now. Just to make sure I can finish this off correctly, this shows that $U-I$ is nill potent because $D_0 ^{-1}N$ is upper triangular meaning it is nilpotent?

Comment: Yes, you are right.. More precisely, it is because you know $D_0 N = N D_0$ (one says, $N$ and $D_0$ *commute*) and thus, $N$ and $D^{-1}_0$ commute as well. Now if you know that $N$ is nilpotent, let us say $N^k = 0$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, take $U^k$ and see what happens.

Comment: I see what you mean. However, I am struggling to find the fault with my previous argument. Is it not true that if  $D_0$ is diagonal and $N$ is upper triangular that $D_0 ^{-1} N$ is upper triangular?

Comment: Yes, it is correct what you wrote. But you should be careful what *upper triangular* means. Usually one refers to upper triangular matrices as those, which has $0$'s below its diagonal. But you for sure mean *upper triangular with $0$'s on its diagonal*. But as I said, your reasoning is totally fine. (To finish your argument, you just have to argue why the conjugation by $P^{-1}$ does not change the nilpotency nature of $D^{-1}_0N$, i.e. why is $P^{-1}(D^{-1}_0N)P$ still nilpotent. *Hint*: recall what remains invariant under conjugations).

Comment: I think that it suffices to note that under a change of basis, which is the given conjugation, the minimal polynomial (and characteristic equation) is invariant.

Comment: Exactly, which implies that the eigenvalues MUST be the same, thus nilpotency (= only eigenvalue is $0$) is invariant under conjugation.